# Commerce Create Cart/Order without product

Tags: commerce

```
function create_init_order() {
  global $user;

  $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);

  if(!$order) {

    $new_order = commerce_order_new($user->uid, 'pending');


    // just consider i have generateEmail() and randomName($len) functions

    $new_order->order_number = $order_number = randomName(10);
    $new_order->mail = generateEmail();
    $new_order->hostname = randomName(10);

    commerce_order_save($new_order);
    unset($new_order);

    $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid); 
    $order->data['suburbs'] = $_REQUEST['suburb'];
    $order->data['truck'] = $_REQUEST['truck_size'];
    commerce_order_save($order);

  }
}
```

Hi guys this is for anonymous user creation of order if not existing yet, anything I missed why is not working well.

Specifically this part:

```
    $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid); 
    $order->data['suburbs'] = $_REQUEST['suburb'];
    $order->data['truck'] = $_REQUEST['truck_size'];
    commerce_order_save($order);
```

As i need suburbs and truck data before adding the line item.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working well"?

Comment: $order->data['suburbs'] = $_REQUEST['suburb'];
 $order->data['truck'] = $_REQUEST['truck_size']; are not saved!

Answer (score 0):

You are unsetting `$new_order` and then calling `commerce_order_save($new_order);` when $new_order is null. It should use $order there.  i.e.

not:

```
commerce_order_save($new_order);
unset($new_order);

$order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid); 
$order->data['suburbs'] = $_REQUEST['suburb'];
$order->data['truck'] = $_REQUEST['truck_size'];
commerce_order_save($new_order);
```

but instead:

```
commerce_order_save($new_order);
unset($new_order);

$order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid); 
$order->data['suburbs'] = filter_xss($_REQUEST['suburb']);
$order->data['truck'] = filter_xss($_REQUEST['truck_size']);     
commerce_order_save($order); // here
```

It also looks like there's no need to save and reload the order there when one save would suffice.

Edit: OP has changed the `$new_order` code typo.

No need to save and load the order, the order_id is already in `$new_order->order_id` after saving in `commerce_order_save($new_order);`

Your problem is probably a `NULL` or empty `$_REQUEST` var. 
Alternatively, you could add the fields to the order entity itself via the Fields UI.

Comment: Hi David, i actually edit my post and add more info. Can you double check please, i am actually unsetting $new_order (just to make sure) and load it on $order and save $order with data.

Comment: @axscode, so you fixed the $new_order / $order variable mixup there? If so, and problem persists, answer updated with other alternative solution.

Comment: Yeah, problem still persist :(